# In unity 2 diffrent game panel 2 diffrent actions is posibble?

Tags: unity-game-engine, emulation

I'am making a online game and i want to test my game in live action (without building all the time). I need 2 or more emulator running and when change my code it must be reload instantly. Is there a way to achive this? Like in react native when i open 4 emulator and change my code all reload and all 4 separate from each other.

Comment: ParrelSync might be helpful for you https://github.com/VeriorPies/ParrelSync

Comment: @DigvijaysinhGohil thanks man i guess this is work just fine :D